# Log class function calls php

Tags: php, class, oop, extends

I'm working on a wrapper function around a existing class.

```
<?php 
    class wrapper extends client {
        public function __call($name,$args) {
            var_dump($name);
            var_dump($args);
        }
    }

    $client = new wrapper();
    $client->users()->foobar();
?>
```

And my response is:

```
    string(5) "users"
    array(0) {
    }
```

My goal is to log which function is called and with the params.

How can I see that the function foobar() on the users class was called. Instead of only "users"? Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is implementing the **Decorator** Pattern and not just extend the class. This is very easy since we have those magic methods you already used. But you missed two essential parts in your wrapper class:

- Instantiate the wrapped child class
- relay function call to child class

Your extension would not work as the magic **__call** method is only called if the class does not have a methd with given name. So you need the Wrapper Decorator class which does not have those methods.

Sample:

```
class BetterWrapper {
    protected $child;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->child = new Client();
    }

    public function __call($name,$args) {
        var_dump($name);
        var_dump($args);

        return call_user_func_array(array($this->child, $name), $args);
    }
}
```

Try this one instead.

See this doc for mechanics of the __call method: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call